# Flutter Android back button navigating back to main page

Tags: android, dart, flutter, back-button

I would like to be able to use the back button to navigate back to the main page instead of closing the app, I have seen the WillPopScope widget option but that needs to show a dialog, is there a way to pop back using the android back button without a dialog?

Comment: WillPopScore doesn't need to show a dialog at all. You can do whatever you like with it.

Comment: I believe the way Flutter acts around back button has changed now, instead of closing the app, it now goes back to previous screen. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Use Navigator.canPop() Method to avoid app from Exiting.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        return Navigator.canPop(context);
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('HomePage')),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sir this code works fine. but if there is no navigation i mean user is on home screen then after clicking the back button application should be closed.

Comment: As of version 3.16 WillPopScope has been deprecated. the replacement is PopScope. Simply providing with canPop: false will disable the popping of current route. If you need to execute some code on back press, use onPopInvoked parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The onWillPop callback needs a Future of bool returned. You just can do

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        return Future.value(true); // or return Future.value(false);
      },
      child: Container()
    );
}
```

Comment: This will only disable the back button